# OpenGL draw a line then a square

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, game-loop

I am having problem managing my code and imagining a good design. What i wanna do is simply draw a line first, then after line has been rendered, draw the square so it overlaps the line partially and then keep on doing this.

I created 2 classes, `Lines` and `Squares`. I have set up and bounded a VAO and a VBO in the main class. In my lines and squares classes i only pass the data to this buffer and make appropriate calls to `VertexAttribPointer` and `GlDrawArrays` in their `draw()` method.

In the main class there is a main game loop that runs infinitely till the user closes the window. Now what i want to do is call the `draw()` method of both `Lines` and `Squares` in an `Update()` method. After this `Render()` is called which only swaps buffers and polls events. Basically a rough sketch is...

```
while(window_close != true)
{   
    update();
    render();
}

public void update()
{
   GL11.glClearColor(0.2f,0.4f,0.3f, 1);
   GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  
   lines.draw();  // object of Lines class
   squares.draw();   // object of Squares class
}

public void render()
{
   swapbuffers(); 
}
```

But there is a problem since update is in a loop it'll feed lines data into the buffer then it'll overwrite that data with squares one. I want it to alternate i.e render lines, then square. Hence i thought to have a flag inside each class. Before the `draw()` methods feed data they would check which one has been rendered and then draw accordingly or else return and do nothing.

Furthermore since at the start of `Update()` The background is cleared, i need to draw lines, render it, then draw squares and render it before clearing the background. I know i could do

```
while(window_close != true)
{  
   GL11.glClearColor(0.2f,0.4f,0.3f, 1);
   GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
   lines.draw();
   render();
   squares.draw();
}
```

which is ok, but for bigger projects it'd become ugly. i'd have to write `render()` alternatively.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What you are doing right now is what most people do.

Comment: I didn't know that.. I thought there must be some other way such that i don't have to do anything after the call to `render()` and everything is managed by `update()`

Comment: Ahhh waitwaitwaitwait, I am having trouble understanding what is the problem. What you want is to swap buffers alternatively?

Comment: @fordcars -  Check my original question now. The last snippet of code is what i want. but i want to do it in a different way such that all the calls to `draw()` are in the update method.

Comment: Ok, uh you shouldn't have this problem! I'll try to explain it breifly; `swapBuffers()` does nothing you would normally care about in this way. When you call anything like `glDrawArrays()`, OpenGL draws stuff into a framebuffer. So, you would draw the line, then the square just fine, since it will only modify the framebuffer where the shape is actually located (so it would overlap like you would like). Then, all `swapBuffers()` does is that it copies, pixel-by-pixel, everything from that framebuffer onto the screen.

Comment: You simply should not have the problem you are having right now because of this. `swapBuffers()` should only be called **once** per frame! It would be great if you posted the actual drawing code in your question. Maybe you are rendering the scene as a texture or something? It would be great to see everything.

Comment: Also, if you are using depth test, you need to clear the depth buffer using `glClear` too!

Comment: damn, i didn't know how `swapbuffers()` worked. Thanks for telling me that, everything is fine now. I thought we could write to buffer only one time after that we must swap the buffers before writing again. Thanks again @fordcars